# get value from onserverclick in c#

Tags: c#

how to get value from row in gridview using button to serverclick ?

this is my code :

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvwListApprover" runat="server" Width="460px">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="No" FieldName="Sequential" Width="20px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="KodePosition" FieldName="KodePosition" Width="175px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Jabatan" FieldName="NamaPosition" Width="175px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Nama" FieldName="UserLogin" Width="265px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn ReadOnly="True" Caption="Action">
                        <DataItemTemplate>
                           <input type="button" id="btnDelApp" onserverclick="btnDelApp_ServerClick('<%#Eval("KodePosition")%>');" value="Delete" runat="server" class="lookupstyle" />
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

from onserverclick, i want get value to codebehind.

```
protected void btnDelApp_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //how to get value from row in gridview event button on serverclick ?              
}
```

please corrected and give me solution.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U Can go with the RowDataBoundEvent of the click.
DO Not Add any explict event for the control.
The GridView Automatically detects the event for the control clicked within it.

```
protected void grdClickDoubleClick_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) //formatted the c# code

{ 

     GridViewRow row = e.Row;

     if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

     {

          //*******************************************************8

          // code here. (This code given below)

          //

     }

}
```

for single click event assign

```
 LinkButton _singleClickButton = row.FindControl("lnkBtnClk") asLinkButton;

 string _jsSingleClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "");

 e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", _jsSingleClick);
```

for double click event assign

```
 LinkButton _dblClickButton = row.FindControl("lnkBtnDblClk") asLinkButton;

 string _jsDoubleClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_dblClickButton, "");

 e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", _jsDoubleClick);
```

This assigned events we can handle in row command method as below.

```
protected void grdClickDoubleClick_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{

     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

     switch (e.CommandName)

     {

          case"clk": //"clk" is command name of linkButton Row click event handler

               grdClickDoubleClick.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;

          break;

          case"dblClk"://"dblClk" is command name of linkButton Row Double click event handler.

               row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;

          break;

     }

}
```

If we want to handle both click and double click then we have to change the above click handler a bit as below

```
 LinkButton _singleClickButton = row.FindControl("lnkBtnClk") asLinkButton;

 string _jsSingleClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "");



 ///We make the script as below format.

 //javascript:setTimeout("POSTBACK SCRIPT", 500)

 _jsSingleClick = _jsSingleClick.Insert(11, "setTimeout(\"");

 _jsSingleClick += "\", 500)";



 e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", _jsSingleClick);
```

then we can handle both row click and double click.

Comment: What if the row has a column with an anchor link, something like this: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click" runat="server" id="aD" onserverclick=""><asp:Image ID="im" CssClass='<%# ((string)Eval("OverrideStatus") == "Pending") ? "delEntryIcon" : "hideTag" %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="delEntry.png" /></a>`?